# How to link to a template in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress and till now, Google help me to find problem I encounter... except this one.

In simple HTML static site, I can link to a "SimplePage.html" page with

```
<a href="SimplePage.html">
    Link to Simple Page
</a>
```

But in WordPress, I just can't find (yet) how to do this. I created the template SimplePage.php then create a page that link to it in wp-admin dashboard  but I don't know how to create a link that point to that SimplePage.php template.

*Additional info:*

should it be something like this:

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/SimplePage">
```

Let's suppose I want create that link in my footer. how do I create this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can do it using Link Manager

[image: Link Manager]

2) you can do it using plugin [Page Link to Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/)

3) you can edit the header.php and insert the link

Comment: What the link should be? that's what I need to know.

Comment: i believe the plugin is already exist inside wordpress, it should be something called blogroll, try find it.

Comment: I find this While googling, but all the example I found are for a link to a given post, I just need link for to a simple template.